# Adding padding causes vertical alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I have a header that contains two hrefs on the left and a navbar on the right. I'm having issues getting everything to be vertically aligned middle. I've gone through the million questions regarding vertical alignment issues but nothing has fixed my issue.

If I add padding to the menu label, the hrefs are no longer vertically aligned by middle. If the padding for the menu is 0, everything is aligned fine. Does navbar need a height and width?

```css
.menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border: red 3px solid;
    padding: 10px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#header nav{
    display:inline;
}
#header {
    background: gray;
    padding: 28px 0 26px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;

}
a[href="#top"] {
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a img{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
a, a:visited{
     color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header"> 
        <a href="#top">Test</a>
        <a href="">
            <img src="" alt="img" height="24" width="24">
        </a>
        <nav id="navbar">
         <label class="menu">Menu</label>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should be aligned to what?

Comment: All of the elements should be in a straigh line according to their centers vertically. The menu label is not in that line with the two hrefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited fiddle** This should work for you https://jsfiddle.net/5f3pbg8b/13/

**note:** You cannot use `vertical-align: middle;` with a floated element, this is because floated elements are aligned to the top, you can read more about it here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats

```
.menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    position: absolute;/* new */
    right: 0;/* new */
    margin-right: 100px;
    border: red 3px solid;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: -10px;/* new */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didn't know that about floats, so I'll have to read up. Is there a way to still get the Menu on the right side? Or would that just require adding a margin left?

Comment: @eric did you look at the fiddle? It is moved to the right.

Comment: @eric here is the correct fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5f3pbg8b/13/ I used the wrong line comments oops

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!